# How to create localization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How to create localization in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project?

I want to have two languages in my app, I heard it has something to do with a Resourses-file, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

1. Create a class library project for your localized resources
2. Add a resource file called `Resource.resx`.
3. Open the file and change the `Access Modifier` drop down to `Public`. Now if you look at the properties of your file, the `Custom Tool` property will be set to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`. This will create a `static` `class` called `Resource` at compile time with all the string names you add.
4. Add your `Name`/`Value` pairs here for your default language.
5. Add a second resource file called `Resource.fr-FR.resx` for example.
6. Add the names you added to the previous resource file here with the French `Values`
7. Add a reference to this class library from your MVC application.
8. Change the culture as needed in your application and use `Resource.NameOfProperty` to access your various localized strings. There is a `ResourceManager` `class` that will handle getting the correct value based on the set culture. All you have to do is follow the naming convention for the resource files. `Resource.{culture-code}.resx`.

---

After creating the class library project as above, here is one option for switching between cultures in your MVC application.

*Add a route, something like this, so your culture can be passed via the URL*

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultCultureRoute",
    "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        culture = "en",
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

*Create an attribute for setting the culture that can be applied to a controller*

```
public class ApplyCulture : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("culture"));

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }
}
```

*Add this attribute to a base controller which all your controllers inherit from*

```
[ApplyCulture]
public class BaseController : Controller { }
```

*Accessing a resource is as simple as this*

```
Resource.NameOfProperty
```